# request list of comments posted on page over last 72h?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So far, I have been unable to figure out how to coerce the FB APIs to get me a list of comments *I* posted on a page over the last 72h.

I tried to get the list of all comments on the page over the last 72h using the graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/):

```
last_72h = int(time.time()) - 72 * 60 * 60
args = {'fields' :  'id,comments.since(%d).fields(id,from.fields(id),likes,created_time,comments.since(%d).fields(id,from.fields(id),likes,created_time))' % (last_72h, last_72h),
        'filter' : 'stream',
        'access_token' : page.page_access_token}
relative_url = '%s/posts?%s' % (page.page_id, urllib.urlencode(args))
```

But the above returns comments that are older than 72h.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a bit of digging, it appears that this is not possible for now. There are a couple of hints about this in the response we get from the FB servers but the main one is that the data structure returned does not support time-based iteration so, according to the docs, the 'since' keyword should not affect them.